# Numpy multiplication matrix (more than two matrix)

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, multiplication

If I need to do multiplication between 5 matrix (taking into account the good shape of the matrix to be able to multiplicate), `np.dot` doesn't work. For ex, in matlab you can easily write:

```matlab
Rf = T^-1 * S^-1 * R * S * T
```

Comment: Use `@` in numpy, it works like `*` in MATLAB (i.e. it is the matrix-multiplication operator): `Rf = np.inv(T) @ np.inv(S) @ R @ S @ T`. btw what do you mean by `T^-1` in MATLAB, did you mean matrix inverse or element-wise inverse?

Comment: Thanks. It works but actually it work with * too. Only np.dot supports max three matrix

Comment: No `*` in numpy is element-wise multiplication, it is the same as `.*` in MATLAB.

Comment: Nested dots can be used `dot(R, dot(S,T))`.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? I'm not sure I understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

to multiply two matrices you can use:
np.matmul(matrix1, matrix2).shape
then use for loop to multiply 5 matrices.

for more info check numpy documentation :
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html

Comment: You can... but you can also just use `@` which is the `np.matmul` operator.